# jQuery - Create columns based on number of instances of an element within an active Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working with a plugin where I don't have access to the HTML, however I can add CSS and Javascript. I am looking to do the following:

1. Check if a div with specific class is active
2. If 'active' find all instances of label within the element
3. For all groups of 8 instances of the element put into a column (33% width of parent container)
4. If less than 8 do nothing

I have tried a number of different ways but am struggling. Here is an example of my code so far:

```js
function columnSnap() {
  $('.productFilter').each(function() {

    if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
      $(this).find('label').addClass('randomClass');
      if ($('.randomClass').length >= 8) {
        //Get next 8 instances and group within a created div
        //Continue until number of instances of randomClass finishes
      }
    }
  });
}
columnSnap();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="productFilter">
  <div class="randomDiv">
  </div>
  <div class="checklist">
    <label class="randomClass"></label>
    <label class="randomClass"></label>
    <label class="randomClass"></label>
    <label class="randomClass"></label>
    <label class="randomClass"></label>
    <label class="randomClass"></label>
    <label class="randomClass"></label>
    <label class="randomClass"></label>
    <label class="randomClass"></label>
    <label class="randomClass"></label>
    <label class="randomClass"></label>
    <label class="randomClass"></label>
    <label class="randomClass"></label>
    <label class="randomClass"></label>
    <label class="randomClass"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Sort of know what I want to do but really struggling to implement it. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Should be `.productFilter`

Comment: @gaganshera ah yes, that was in my original code, have just amended this now.

Comment: @mplungjan I am able to find when the element is visible and then assign class, it's the grouping of 8 and creating a column that I'm puzzled about...

Comment: How do you mean grouping? Just do a `$('.randomClass').each` in your if condition to loop through the elements.

Comment: @gaganshera I want to put every 8 instances into a div that will be created dynamically. If there isn't 8 instances I want the function to do nothing...

Comment: Added an answer. Check it it fits the bill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am adding the solution for this, but I want to point out a basic flaw in your code.
The line which says `if ($('.randomClass').length >= 8) {` is incorrect.
It is incorrect in the sense that it will count the number of labels **in total**.
This would be wrong because I believe your intention is to deal with groups of 8 labels **within each** `productFilter`

Consider that there are 2 productFilter divs, first with 5 labels and second with 4 labels. As is your intention, they should NOT get grouped together as the number of labels within each productFIlter div is less than 8. But they will incorrectly get grouped together because the code mentioned above will count the total labels as 9 (5+4) i.e > 8

So that part should be changed to :

```
if ($(this).find('.randomClass').length >= 8)
```

Okay, now with that explained. I am putting the code snippet below. Here's the [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/shariqkhan/tac5qg01/7/) for the same

```js
function columnSnap() {
 jQuery('.productFilter').each(function(){
  i = 0;
  if(jQuery(this).is(":visible")) {
   jQuery(this).find('label').addClass('randomClass');
   lenChild = jQuery(this).find('.randomClass').length;
   if (lenChild >= 8) {
    var parentContainer = jQuery(this);      
    
    v2 = (Math.floor(lenChild/8) * 8);
    parentElem = 0;
    jQuery(this).find('.randomClass').each(function(){
     if(i < v2) {     
      if(i%8 == 0) {
       if(i != 0) 
        jQuery(parentElem).appendTo(jQuery(parentContainer));
       //parentElem = jQuery('#instancecontainer .instanceHolder').clone();
       parentElem = jQuery('<div class="instanceHolder"></div>');
      }
      jQuery(this).appendTo(jQuery(parentElem));
      i++;
     }
    });
    jQuery(parentElem).appendTo(jQuery(parentContainer));   
   }
  }
 });
}

jQuery('#move').click(function(){
 columnSnap();
});
```

```css
.productFilter {
  border:2px solid #ccc;
  margin:20px 0;
}
.randomClass {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
  min-width:10px;
  margin:5px;
  background:red;
}
.instanceHolder {
  border:2px solid green;
  margin:10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="productFilter">
    <div class="randomDiv">
    </div>
    <div class="checklist">
        <label class="randomClass">1</label>
        <label class="randomClass">2</label>
        <label class="randomClass">3</label>
        <label class="randomClass">4</label>
        <label class="randomClass">5</label>
        <label class="randomClass">6</label>
        <label class="randomClass">7</label>
        <label class="randomClass">8</label>
        <label class="randomClass">9</label>
        <label class="randomClass">10</label>
        <label class="randomClass">11</label>
        <label class="randomClass">12</label>
        <label class="randomClass">13</label>
        <label class="randomClass">14</label>
        <label class="randomClass">15</label>
        <label class="randomClass">16</label>
        <label class="randomClass">17</label>
        <label class="randomClass">18</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="productFilter">
    <div class="randomDiv">
    </div>
    <div class="checklist">
        <label class="randomClass">1</label>
        <label class="randomClass">2</label>
        <label class="randomClass">3</label>
        <label class="randomClass">4</label>
        <label class="randomClass">5</label>
        <label class="randomClass">6</label>
        <label class="randomClass">7</label>
        <label class="randomClass">8</label>
        <label class="randomClass">9</label>
        <label class="randomClass">10</label>
        <label class="randomClass">11</label>
        <label class="randomClass">12</label>
        <label class="randomClass">13</label>
        <label class="randomClass">14</label>
        <label class="randomClass">15</label>
        <label class="randomClass">16</label>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="move">Move</button>
```

Comment: Hi @shariqkhan thanks for this, however I don't have access to the HTML which means adding the instancecontainer and instanceHolder becomes problematic. Not sure if the answer above reflects this at all? Any ideas?

Comment: thank you for your help, the answer worked. Just a follow up question if possible. How would I go about achieving the same if I had a label and then a div, and this continued. So I could add both elements to the new instanceHolder at each evaluation? Thanks!

Comment: In that case, you can use one of the following lines:

1.jQuery(this).prev('div').appendTo(jQuery(parentElem));
 2.jQuery(this).next('div').appendTo(jQuery(parentElem));
 3.jQuery(this).siblings('div').eq(0).appendTo(jQuery(parentElem));

Use line 1, if you are sure that div will appear BEFORE the label
Use line 2,  if you are sure that div will appear AFTER the label
Use line 3, if you are NOT sure of the relative order of div and label

Whichever line you decide to use, should be appended to this line:
jQuery(this).appendTo(jQuery(parentElem));